# Trigonometry Interval Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What does the interval $-\pi, \pi$ mean? Would it include $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you mean one of $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $(-\pi,\pi)$, no?

Answer (score 3):

Both of those numbers are included on that interval. Check your notation, too. Square brackets and round ones mean different things. If you write $(-\pi,\pi)$, then you mean all real numbers satisfying $-\pi < x< \pi$. If you write $[-\pi,\pi]$, then you mean all real numbers satisfying $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$.

In either case, $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ are both on the interval.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs. I suppose that some $-$ signs are missing in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You see this kind of question a lot in Math 12 trigonometry and up. For example, if your teacher asks you to "Graph the function $f(x)=sin(x)$ in the interval $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$", that means that you have to pretend the *domain* of the function is restricted to the interval $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$, and graph the function like how it would appear if the domain is just $-\pi \le x \le \pi$. To answer your second question, yes, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ are both located in the interval $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$. But values like $2\pi$ and $-3.5\pi$ are located outside the interval.